# Accessing property map for surface mesh

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a `CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3>` to which I added a property map

```
Mesh::Property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color>
    color_map = tin_colored_mesh.add_property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color>("f:color").first;
```

I had this map populated.

Afterwards, I try to access this property map again as below:

```
std::string name = "f:color";
const Mesh::Property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color> ans = tin_colored_mesh.property_map(name).first;
```

However this raises an error:

```
/Users/<path to file>:197:82: error: no matching member function for call to 'property_map'
  const Mesh::Property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color> ans = tin_colored_mesh.property_map(name).first;
                                                                
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/Surface_mesh.h:1974:40: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'I'
    std::pair<Property_map<I, T>,bool> property_map(const std::string& name) const
```

I am not sure how to correctly use the templates here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for CGAL::Surface_mesh](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh.html#ad26d6c09eb532fd5faddc39f9034f462) the `property_map` member function is a [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template) just as the `add_property_map` member function that you use above.

As the error states, C++ fails to infer the template argument I that the function template `CGAL::Surface_mesh::property_map` expects. A potential solution would be to supply the required template arguments just as you did for `add_property_map`:

```
const Mesh::Property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color> ans
  = tin_colored_mesh.property_map<Mesh::Face_index, CGAL::Color>(name).first;
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oops. I was trying out few examples and it was an embarrassing miss that I didn't see how it was being done in add_property_map. Thanks.